# Position elements dynamically- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three images in `<section>`

```
<section class="one">
          <img src="one.png" />
        </section>

        <section class="two">
          <img src="two.png" />
        </section>

        <section class="three">
          <img src="three.png" />
        </section>
```

I have added some css to position the sections:

```
$('.one').css({
      position:'absolute',
      top:100
    });
    $('.two').css({
      position:'absolute',
      top:800
    });

    $('.three').css({
      position:'absolute',
      top:1600
    });
```

My problem is in the js - I want to position each element dynamically so for example the first section would be top 100px the section one would be 200px and the third one would be 300px.  This is what i have managed so far:

```
    $.fn.inView = function(){
    var win = $(window);
    obj = $(this);
    var scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
    var visibleArea = win.scrollTop() + win.height();
    var objEndPos = (obj.offset().top + obj.outerHeight());
    var visible =(visibleArea >= objEndPos && scrollPosition <= objEndPos);
    $.each( obj, function( index ) {
        if(visible){
            //console.log(index);
            $(obj).css({
                position:'fixed',
                top: index*100//Problem here

            }); 
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you had there was that you set the css of the `obj` jquery selector, and not on the `img` that was in the `obj` selector.
In order to get to the `img` element you could use any of `$(this)` or add a second parameter to the callback function inside the `$.each`, which is the current element:

```
$.each(obj, function(index, el) {
    $(el).css
```

Here is a complete snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  obj = $('section img');
  $.each(obj, function(index) {
    $(this).css({
      position:'fixed',
      top: index*100
    });
  });
});
```

```css
section img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
section.one img {
  border-color: red;
}
section.two img {
  border-color: green;
}
section.three img {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="one">
  <img src="one.png" alt="one"/>
</section>
<section class="two">
  <img src="two.png" alt="two" />
</section>

<section class="three">
  <img src="three.png" alt="three" />
</section>
```